# How can I make a full screen java application?

Tags: java, css, image, fullscreen, fxml

I have an image viewer appplication. It works perfectly, but I'd like to make a full screen mode for it. It's an FXML project in Netbeans so, the main java is a separated file, therefore I cannot use this:

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```

because I can't reach the stage from my main .java file.

So I have a file, its name is imageViewer.java, it has this:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("image_view.fxml"));  
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        String css = this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
        stage.setMinHeight(640);
        stage.setMinWidth(960);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

and I have another file, it has fxml implements, and the ActionEvent void methods, you know, click the button, next picture etc...

The mentioned method (start method above) it's a method, therefore I can't return the stage. I have to reach the stage from image_viewController.java (the main java), what includes the other methods, functions and FXML implements etc...

I'd like to do this:

```
public void fullScreen(ActionEvent e) {
      stage.setFullScreen(true);
}
```

But I can't reach the stage from another .java file. This is the first problem. And the second problem.

How can I make position absolute my panes, Vboxes etc like in html??? If my ImageView (what contains my image) get the full width and height, pulls down my HBox (what includes the buttons). If HBox were in absolute position, it wouldn't happened this, would it?

And the final problem, how can I make that, my HBox doesn't appear, just triggered by a hover effect. Is it possible with a separated css file? As I know, it is possible to make with FXML files.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Pass the Stage trough your Constructors

Comment: And how can I do this. I'm a beginner, I programming in java just a week ago. :)